# No results are coming in YQL Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, yql

What could be the YQL Query to extract movie data from IMDB website. I need to fetch cast information from the title page of IMDB which i have as input URL.

**Ex:**

**My input URL :** http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1243957/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple get request is an answer to this.

```
 $.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1243957/",
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }//end function(data)
 );//end getJSON
```

Answer (score 0):

Not javascript, but here is `curl` command which sends YQL query to fetch cast information:

```
$ curl -G --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "www.imdb.com/title/tt1243957/" AND xpath="//div[contains(@id,'\''titleCast'\'')]"' http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=xml
```